# Error when I trying to run a trained ner model on local pc

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, nlp, named-entity-recognition

```
import re
import pickle
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import TFSMLayer
import numpy as np

class CustomNonPaddingTokenLoss(keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self, reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO, name="custom_ner_loss"):
        super().__init__(reduction=reduction, name=name)

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        loss_fn = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
            from_logits=False, reduction=self.reduction
        )
        loss = loss_fn(y_true, y_pred)
        mask = tf.cast((y_true > 0), dtype=tf.float32)
        loss = loss * mask
        return tf.reduce_sum(loss) / tf.reduce_sum(mask)

def map_record_to_training_data(record):
    record = tf.strings.split(record, sep="\t")
    length = tf.strings.to_number(record[0], out_type=tf.int32)
    tokens = record[1 : length + 1]
    tags = record[length + 1 :]
    tags = tf.strings.to_number(tags, out_type=tf.int64)
    tags += 1
    return tokens, tags

def lookup(tokens):
    # Load the list from the file
    with open('./resources/vocabulary.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        loaded_list = pickle.load(f)
    # The StringLookup class will convert tokens to token IDs
    lookup_layer = keras.layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=loaded_list)

    # No need to lowercase Vietnamese characters
    return lookup_layer(tokens)

def format_datatype(data):
    tokens =  [re.sub(r'[;,]', '', d) for d in data.split(' ')]
    #default is 0, since is for prediction
    ner_tags = [0 for d in data.split(' ')]

    #tab to separate
    string_input = str(len(tokens))+ "\t"+ "\t".join(tokens)+ "\t"+ "\t".join(map(str, ner_tags))
    string_input = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([string_input])

    
    finalize_input = (string_input.map(map_record_to_training_data)
                      .map(lambda x, y: (lookup(x),  y))
                      .padded_batch(1)
                      )

    return finalize_input

def prediction(data):
    # Register the custom loss function with TensorFlow
    tf.keras.utils.get_custom_objects()['CustomNonPaddingTokenLoss'] = CustomNonPaddingTokenLoss
    loaded_model = Sequential()
    loaded_model.add(TFSMLayer("./resources/ner_model", call_endpoint='serving_default'))


    all_predicted_tag_ids = []
    
    for x, _ in data:
        print("Input Tensor Info:")
        print("Data Type:", x.dtype)
        print("Shape:", x.shape)
        x = tf.cast(x, tf.int64)
        output = loaded_model(x, training=False)
        predictions = np.argmax(output, axis=-1)
        predictions = np.reshape(predictions, [-1])
        all_predicted_tag_ids.append(predictions)

    all_predicted_tag_ids = np.concatenate(all_predicted_tag_ids)

    ner_labels = ["[PAD]", "N", "M", "other"]
    mapping =  dict(zip(range(len(ner_labels)), ner_labels))
    predicted_tags = [mapping[tag] for tag in all_predicted_tag_ids]

    return predicted_tags

sample_input = "Hello world, my name is John, I live in New York, my birthday is 10/02/1990."

result = prediction(format_datatype(sample_input))
print(result)
```

I trained the model on google colab, and download the model and try to load in on my window pc.
*It work fine on google colab, even when I restart and clear the terminal and just run this block of code, there are no error at all.
When I move to pc, I found that I need to load the model with a lot of pre-step, unlike on google colab just a (model = load_model("xxx/xxx"))

I am encountering an issue while using the **`TFSMLayer`** in TensorFlow, where I receive the following error message

-----------------------------------------

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Exception encountered when calling TFSMLayer.call().

cannot compute __inference_signature_wrapper_1285 as input #0(zero-based) was expected to be a int64 tensor but is a float tensor [Op:__inference_signature_wrapper_1285]

-------------------------------------------

I'm trying to load a TensorFlow model that uses the **`TFSMLayer`** for inference, but it seems that the input tensor received by the **`TFSMLayer.call()`** method is of data type **`float32`**, while the model expects **`int64`**. This inconsistency leads to an error during computation.

I have already attempted to cast the input tensor to **`int64`** using **`tf.cast`** before passing it to the loaded model, but the error persists.

I'm uncertain why the input tensor's data type is being converted to **`float32`**, and how to resolve this issue. Any insights or suggestions on how to debug and resolve this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Can you share the values you got from those print statements

Comment: Input Tensor Info:
Data Type: <dtype: 'int64'>
Shape: (1, 15) And here the output shows the tf dtype are int64, so this is where Im confused

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it might be tensorflow version issue.
I try to uninstall tensorflow on pc (2.16.1) and install the same version as google colab (2.15.0) and the original code run smoothly.

```html
import re
import pickle
import keras
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
print(tf.__version__)
class CustomNonPaddingTokenLoss(keras.losses.Loss):
    def __init__(self, reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO, name="custom_ner_loss"):
        super().__init__(reduction=reduction, name=name)

    def call(self, y_true, y_pred):
        loss_fn = keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(
            from_logits=False, reduction=self.reduction
        )
        loss = loss_fn(y_true, y_pred)
        mask = tf.cast((y_true > 0), dtype=tf.float32)
        loss = loss * mask
        return tf.reduce_sum(loss) / tf.reduce_sum(mask)

def map_record_to_training_data(record):
    record = tf.strings.split(record, sep="\t")
    length = tf.strings.to_number(record[0], out_type=tf.int32)
    tokens = record[1 : length + 1]
    tags = record[length + 1 :]
    tags = tf.strings.to_number(tags, out_type=tf.int64)
    tags += 1
    return tokens, tags

def lookup(tokens):
    # Load the list from the file
    with open('./resources/vocabulary.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        loaded_list = pickle.load(f)
    # The StringLookup class will convert tokens to token IDs
    lookup_layer = keras.layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=loaded_list)

    # No need to lowercase Vietnamese characters
    return lookup_layer(tokens)

def format_datatype(data):
    tokens =  [re.sub(r'[;,]', '', d) for d in data.split(' ')]
    #default is 0, since is for prediction
    ner_tags = [0 for d in data.split(' ')]

    #tab to separate
    string_input = str(len(tokens))+ "\t"+ "\t".join(tokens)+ "\t"+ "\t".join(map(str, ner_tags))
    string_input = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([string_input])

    
    finalize_input = (string_input.map(map_record_to_training_data)
                      .map(lambda x, y: (lookup(x),  y))
                      .padded_batch(1)
                      )

    return finalize_input

def prediction(data):
    # Register the custom loss function with TensorFlow
    tf.keras.utils.get_custom_objects()['CustomNonPaddingTokenLoss'] = CustomNonPaddingTokenLoss
    
    loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model("./resources/ner_model")

    all_predicted_tag_ids = []
    
    for x, _ in data:
        print("Input Tensor Info:")
        print("Data Type:", x.dtype)
        print("Shape:", x.shape)
        x = tf.cast(x, tf.int64)
        output = loaded_model(x, training=False)
        predictions = np.argmax(output, axis=-1)
        predictions = np.reshape(predictions, [-1])
        all_predicted_tag_ids.append(predictions)

    all_predicted_tag_ids = np.concatenate(all_predicted_tag_ids)

    ner_labels = ["[PAD]", "N", "M", "other"]
    mapping =  dict(zip(range(len(ner_labels)), ner_labels))
    predicted_tags = [mapping[tag] for tag in all_predicted_tag_ids]

    return predicted_tags

sample_input = ""Hello world, my name is John, I live in New York, my birthday is 10/02/1990."

result = prediction(format_datatype(sample_input))
print(result)
print(len(result))
```